# A Few Questions About Qt

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform

1. Is it free? It looks like on the website it says *"Try Now"*, which makes me worry that it just gives you a demo.
2. Do you have to pay the Qt company anything to distribute a program using Qt, or can you just throw it (the program) out there and just say you used Qt.
3. Is it native C++, or something weird, like, the same way .NET programs aren't actual C++, they just look like it.
4. Would somebody who uses my program have to install the Qt framework before they can run it, or will the program run without any installation?
5. Can it easily be compiled to work on a Windows, Linux and Mac OS?

P.S.: Pretty sure this question relates to: "software tools commonly used by programmers", I don't see why there are all the dislikes and having the question closed. (Tough crowd)

Comment: Please, one question per question, and stick to actual practical programming questions. Qt's documentation is quite good, including the docs about compiling, deployment on various platforms.

Comment: @Mat - I think these are linked partsof the same question. Yes you can find the answers to all these online - but these answers may be out of date. Qt has been through 3 owners and different licenses in the last few years

Comment: 1 and 2 can be discovered by *reading* the website. 3: yes, it's standard C++, though it ships a custom code preprocessor that you need to integrate into your build process. 4: you can just ship the library yourself. 5: Yes.

Comment: @MartinBeckett: answers here will also get outdated. The official website is the place to go for licensing information, regardless of who owns the stuff today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it free? It looks like on the website it says "Try Now", which
>   makes me worry that it just gives you a demo.

It's LGPL so free-speech and free-beer. You have to release any changes to Qt itself but you can use it for free in your commercial apps. You can buy a commercial license which gives you better support and the right to keep any modifications or additions to the library to yourself.

> Is it native c++, or something weird, like, the same way .NET programs
>   aren't actual c++, they just look like it.

It is c++, there is an extra pre-compile step which generates native C++ code for the GUI and for some special features (signal/slots). For historic reasons it contains its own version of lots of c++ that is now standard (eg. its own equivalent of STL and it's own threading) but you are free to mix STL/boost/Qt types as you wish. It works with any regular c++ compiler.

> Would somebody who uses my program have to install the QT framework
>   before they can run it, or will the program run without any
>   installation?

You need to include the Qt shared libraries (dll/so) that you use, along with your apps.
On linux you can use the system Qt libs, on windows it's trickier to mix dlls across compilers.

> Can it easily be compiled to work on a Windows, Linux and Mac OS?

It's easy to build, `configure --a list of options for stuff you want` or you can download compiled binaries for all platforms.

Comment: Actually http://qt.digia.com/ (which is top in Google for `qt`) offers only commercial version. LGPL licensed version can be found on http://qt-project.org/

Comment: thanks alot, answered all my questions perfectly!

Comment: also thank you for your response to mats criticism, people on this website are SO touchy about what you say/ask.

Answer (score 2):

(It's spelled "Qt", not "QT", btw.)

1. You went to the wrong website. Instead, go to the [Qt Project](http://qt-project.org) website. Qt is free and open source (LGPL and GPL). The commercial license, as offered by Digia, is optional.
2. You don't need to pay anything if you don't buy a commercial license. When you distribute your program, you need to comply with the terms of either the GPL or the LGPL, according to which of those two licenses you pick.
3. It's native C++, except for the QML module, which uses a JavaScript engine. The QML module is optional; you can stick to C++ if you want.
4. If you link statically against Qt, then no. If you don't, you need to include the Qt DLLs with your application.
5. I do all three, and it was easy. Actually, to create Windows versions of my application, I cross compile them in Linux using [MXE](http://mxe.cc).

Answer (score 1):

1. [It's dual-licensed](http://qt.digia.com/Product/Licensing/License-Comparison/). You can do almost anything you want if you're producing FOSS. If you produce closed-source commercial software, you can use it for free if its in a DLL/.so, but have to pay if you statically link it into your application.
2. See above. Depends on how you link to it.
3. It's native C++ that runs without any virtual machine or anything like that. It does use a "Meta Object Compiler" (MOC) to produce part of the code, so to do *some* things, you write something in another language, which MOC translates to C++, and compile that.
4. If you link it statically, it will just be in your executable. If you link dynamically, it'll be in a DLL/.so, but I believe you can install that as part of your program (i.e., it'll be in a separate file, but the user doesn't have to install it separately).
5. Yes, reasonably easily anyway.